# Avoid duplicate values in comma delimited sql query

Tags: sql-server

hello I have here a comma delimited query:

```
select [Product_Name] 
,(select  h2.Location_name + ', '  from (select distinct * from [dbo].[Product_list]) h2 where h1.Product_Name = h2.Product_Name 
    order by h2.Product_Name for xml path  ('')) as Location_name  
,(select   h2.[Store name] + ', ' from [dbo].[Product_list] h2 where h1.Product_Name = h2.Product_Name 
    order by h2.Product_Name for xml path  ('')) as store_name, sum(Quantity) as Total_Quantity from [dbo].[Product_list] h1 
group by [Product_Name]
```

but this query shows duplicated data in comma delimited form, my problem is how will I only show the distinct values of the column in comma delimited form? can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.Product_list and instead SELECT DISTINCT location_name FROM dbo.Product_list, which is anyway the only column you need, it will return only distinct values.

> T-SQL supports the use of the asterisk, or “star” character (*) to
>   substitute for an explicit column list. This will retrieve all columns
>   from the source table. While the asterisk is suitable for a quick
>   test, avoid using it in production work, as changes made to the table
>   will cause the query to retrieve all current columns in the table’s
>   current defined order. This could cause bugs or other failures in
>   reports or applications expecting a known number of columns returned
>   in a defined order. Furthermore, returning data that is not needed can
>   slow down your queries and cause performance issues if the source
>   table contains a large number of rows. By using an explicit column
>   list in your SELECT clause, you will always achieve the desired
>   results, providing the columns exist in the table. If a column is
>   dropped, you will receive an error that will help identify the problem
>   and fix your query.
>
> Using SELECT DISTINCT will filter out duplicates in the result set.
>   SELECT DISTINCT specifies that the result set must contain only unique
>   rows. However, it is important to understand that the DISTINCT option
>   operates only on the set of columns returned by the SELECT clause. It
>   does not take into account any other unique columns in the source
>   table. DISTINCT also operates on all the columns in the SELECT list,
>   not just the first one.

From Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012 MCT Manual.